# InputFormTextBox shows raw RTF in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, rich-text, inputformtextbox

I am developing a custom SharePoint page where the data for one of the fields is being pulled in from an Oracle DB. The data is in stored in RTF format like `{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl{\f0\froman Tms Rmn;}{\f1\froman Times New Roman;}}....`

I am using a `InputFormTextBox` and setting the Text property to be the data being pulled from the Oracle DB. Here is the markup for the control:

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="rftDefaultValue" RichText="true"     RichTextMode="FullHtml" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>
```

I have tried experimenting with all the possible values for RichTextMode. However no matter what I do, when the control renders, it shows the data in the raw RTF format.

Is there something I am missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, SharePoint is a browser-based service and does not have any means to render RTF. Therefore, it is no surprise that RTF-formatted text does not render properly in SharePoint.

SharePoint does not recognize RTF formatting tags and conventions, so this text will be displayed *verbatim*.

There are several RTF to HTML converters available on the interwebs. Given your Oracle source, and without any details about how you pull the data from Oracle into the SharePoint site, my best suggestion is to engage your favourite search engine to look for "rtf to html" and sprinkle in the odd mention of "Oracle"

That should at least give you some ideas about how to approach the topic and make it a bit clearer that the problem does not lie with SharePoint, but rather with how the data is *presented* to SharePoint.

Convert the RTF to HTML before serving it to SharePoint and your issue will go away.